# How to access files stored in a password protected folder in windows

Tags: file, groovy, filesystems, password-protection

I need to save/access some text files under a password protected folder on the file system in windows, Is there any way I can access these files inside that password protected folder using groovy/java?

Answer (score 1):

depends on the mechanism of password protection. In general, decrypting / cracking a password protected folder / file requires lots of CPU time & power, or even not possible to be decrypted in forseeable future.